# How to add newline to text file in comprehensive nested list?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, nested-lists

I have a nested list:

```
A = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c'], ['b', 'c'], ['a', 'd']]
```

I want to save list A to multiple text files with the limitation of 2 nested list per text file.

So the output should be like:

in `small_file_2.txt`:

```
a
b
c
d
e

a
a
b
c
```

in `small_file_4.txt`:

```
b
c

a
d
```

I tried this code:

```
lines_per_file = 2
for lineno, line in enumerate(A):
    if lineno % lines_per_file == 0:
        if smallfile:
           smallfile.close()
        small_filename = 'small_file_{}.txt'.format(lineno + lines_per_file)
        smallfile = open(small_filename, "w")
     smallfile.write('\n'.join(str(x) for x in line)+'\n')         
smallfile.close()
```

Unfortunately, the output in text files are not as I expected it to be. It does not print the newline for after every new nested list.

Comment: Please fix your indentation. `smallfile.write` is wrongly indented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix is fairly simple:

`\n.join([])` adds `\n`between every item, but not before and after. The first `\n` you've added just added one afterwards. If you want it separated, you need a second one.

```
lines_per_file = 2
for lineno, line in enumerate(A):
    if lineno % lines_per_file == 0:
        if smallfile:
           smallfile.close()
        small_filename = 'small_file_{}.txt'.format(lineno + lines_per_file)
        smallfile = open(small_filename, "w")
    smallfile.write('\n'.join(str(x) for x in line)+'\n\n')         # <= add a second \n
smallfile.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Second approach with `with` and no empty lines at the end:

```
lines_per_file = 2
for lineno in range(0, len(A), lines_per_file):
    small_filename = 'small_file_{}.txt'.format(lineno + lines_per_file)
    with smallfile = open(small_filename, "w"): #this will close the file by itself
        smallfile.write('\n\n'.join('\n'.join(str(x) for x in A[current])) for current in range(lineno, min(lineno+lines_per_file, len(A)))
```

Let's explain the magic:

```
for lineno in range(0, len(A), lines_per_file):
```

We'll be taking all lines from 0 to lines_per_file-1, then lines_per_file to 2*lines_per_file-1... Until the end.

```
'\n'.join(str(x) for x in A[current])
```

This is what you used, but we call the line directly from A. Parses one line as single characters in multiple lines.

```
'\n\n'.join(...)
```

Parsed lines will have two linebreaks between each other - that means there will be an empty line you wanted.

```
for current in range(lineno, min(lineno+lines_per_file, len(A))
```

As I said, we are taking lines from lineno (that is: 0, lines_per_file, 2*lines_per_file...) until the next step. Or until the end of the A, whichever is shorter (that's why there's min).

Answer (score 1):

Below code will work fine as per your requirement.

```py
lines_per_file = 2
for lineno, line in enumerate(A):
    if lineno % lines_per_file == 0:
        small_filename = 'small_file_{}.txt'.format(lineno + lines_per_file)
    smallfile = open(small_filename, "a")
    smallfile.write('\n'.join(str(x) for x in line)+'\n')
    smallfile.write('\n')
    smallfile.close()
smallfile.close()
```